# Language label is not displayed on projects view

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to create plugin for some custom language for SonarQube.
I downloaded some example code from:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example
This is example plugin for "Foo" language. I installed it, analysed project with .foo file but as you can see on the picture project is not labeled.

[image: SonarQube projects view]

Also language filter is not working for "Foo" projects:
[image]

Does anyone know solution?